# Time.zone.now locked in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In prodction, method `Time.zone.now` always return the same value while `Time.now` returns
the correct system time.

Here one example:

**banner.rb**

```
scope :active, where("'#{Time.zone.now}' between start_date and end_date")
```

**log of this scope:**

```
SELECT `banners`.* FROM `banners` WHERE ('2013-03-06 08:06:46 -0300' between start_date and end_date) AND ((`banners`.`store_id` = 1 AND `banners`.`spot_id` = 3 AND `banners`.`at_home` = 1))
```

`Time.zone.now` is always **2013-03-06 08:06:46 -0300**

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the scope is evaluated once, when the class is loaded.

You should define it like this:

```
def self.active
  where("'#{Time.zone.now}' between start_date and end_date")
end
```

Every time this method is called, it will be re-evaluated and so the time will change.